# Installing Samsung electric range oven on 110V

Tags: power, power-electronics

I just purchased a Samsung electric range oven, NE59M4320SS.

It has a connector cable,

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/smart-choice-6-range-cord/8929671.p?skuId=8929671

As you can see the cord has 3-wire, and is for 220V.

My apartment does only have 110V normal US outlets.

I tried to search for adapters/voltage converters, but this special crowfoot 3-wire connector is called somehow Australian.

I cannot find an adapter that would be the same shape as this crowfoot 3-wire connector, and would convert it to the normal US 110V connector.

Question:

1. Is there any adapter (or voltage converter), that I could use to just convert the voltage, and connect the electric range to the 110V outlet?
2. Or do I need an electrician?

Comment: This question is off topic here, but no, you cannot use that appliance without a 220v run from the breaker panel specifically for it.  A converter is not possible as it exceeds the power delivery rating of a 110v circuit by a factor of four (2x current 2x voltage)

Comment: [Here](https://www.homedepot.com/s/stove%2520cord?NCNI-5) are some typical US-style stove cords. I suggest you get a molded plug/cord rather than trying to fit a universal style plug because the stove will move in and out for cleaning. Chances are there is a socket specifically for the stove in behind the current spot. Electric clothes dryers usually have a similar 240V plug. It's possible  your apartment is 208 rather than 240 which will mean about 25% less power, but it still should be usable.

Answer (score 2):

That range requires a 220 Volt, 40 Amp supply.  It definitely won't work on a normal 120 V 15 or 20 Amp circuit.

If your apartment is wired for an electric stove, there should be a suitable outlet where the stove goes.  There may be a some variation in connector types (40 or 50 Amp, 3 or 4 pin) so you have to get a cable that matches the existing socket.

If the apartment is not wired for an electric stove (was the previous one gas?), you will have to arrange to get a suitable outlet installed.